# (Works in local host but not as heroku app) NoMethodError in Devise::Registrations#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, web, devise

I am unable to understand. As the code works in local host. When I deployed it in heroku. Its not working. I have been working on it for more than 3 hrs to fix it. Unable to do it. I am here in stack overflow. I hope someone here can help me fix it.

[https://reviewappimdbapi.herokuapp.com/users/sign_up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amZXF.jpg)

[Here's the new_users_registration_path.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFJRy.jpg)

[Here's the user model.- user.rb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YK7Jx.jpg)

[Here's route file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnuVE.jpg)
[Heroku logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxNgY.jpg)

Comment: the attribute `name` is obviously missing for your User model, try to rerun the migrations: `heroku run rails db:migrate`

Comment: locally everything works like a charm but as I deploy the app in heroku. In heroku as well, except for the new_user_registration, everything works.

There is t.string :name in schema.rb as well.

Comment: attribute **name** is not missing. I ran heroku **run rake db:migrate** as well. and restarted heroku. I have used devise > 2.0. But still can't figure it out.

Comment: can you provide the error from the log?

Comment: okay @BM5k.. Its above//

Comment: can you confirm all files from your local setup are pushed to heroku

Comment: @ibya404 I don't really see any errors in that log... it definitely sounds like the `name` is missing. Can you run `heroku run rails console` and then `User.column_names` to see if its listed?

One thing to be aware of is that if you ran your database migrations on heroku THEN changed one of them to add the `name` column, that change wouldn't be reflected on heroku EVEN IF you run `heroku rake db:migrate` afterwards.

Comment: I figured it out. Yes, @BM5k, name was missing, `heroku run rake db:migrate` did no change. So, went to heroku dashboard and deleted all database files. After deploying and running `heroku run rake db:migrate` reinstated the missing migration files which were missing somehow. Now, It works like a charm. 
Appreciate your help ya' all. Thank You.